Seeking advice on bad control when the relationship is indirect (overcontrol bias?)
I’m working on a project where we’re trying to estimate the impact of country fragility status on project outcomes. We have data on the total grant funding allocated to each project, which we’ve been including as a control variable in our regressions. However, there’s a concern that grant size may be correlated with fragility status, because the formula used for allocating grants gives countries with certain characteristics (e.g., poorer countries, small island countries) larger grants.
While fragility status is not factored in the formula, the formula takes into account characteristics that are strongly associated with fragility. In other words, country fragility status itself does not directly impact grant funding, but it is correlated with factors that do.
Aside from multicollinearity concerns, would adding grant size as a control introduce bias in this case?

It isn't an issue alone for you to include two correlated variables in a regression, in fact regression by default assumes correlation between predictors. The issue is if the model introduces multicollinearity that is substantial enough to cause issues (e.g. interpreting the explanatory power of one predictor over the other). This we can only know by entering the predictor into the model, but it seems like these are anyway proxy measures that wouldn't have a strong enough correlation for this to matter. The issue would be more obvious if we had a relationship like this.
Based off my loose intuition, I would think that grant funding and your proxies of fragility would likely have an interaction you should model too, in OLS something like:
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{Project Outcomes} &=& \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{Fragility} + \beta_2 \text{Funding} +   \\ 
  & & \beta_3 \text{(Fragility x Funding)} + \epsilon
\end{eqnarray}
where higher levels of fragility may diminish the positive association between grant funding and project outcomes. Or vice versa, where higher levels of funding may offset the effect of fragility on project outcomes. But that is an assumption from myself, a non subject matter expert.
